# Add ORDER BY statement to SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server

I have the following `SELECT` statement and I need to add `ORDER BY [UserName]`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [UserInfo] 
WHERE ([AWSAccountID] = CASE WHEN @AWSAccountID = -1 THEN [AWSAccountID] 
ELSE @AWSAccountID END)
```

I'm having some trouble figuring out where the `ORDER BY` needs to go, assuming it can be added at all.

Comment: This is a totally valid question (it's just easy). It is also not abusive or Indian-style. No reason to downvote it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless I am missing something you just add your `ORDER BY` to the end of the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [UserInfo] 
WHERE ([AWSAccountID] = CASE WHEN @AWSAccountID = -1 THEN [AWSAccountID] 
                           ELSE @AWSAccountID END)
ORDER BY [UserName]
```

Comment: I swear I tried that... but you are 100% right. I'm gonna go get some more coffee. Thank you.